# TFS solution thinks it is still under version control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have unbound all projects from **TFS** version control, but every time I open the solution it pops-up a dialog asking me if I want to connect to **TFS**.

**Q: How do I get rid of it?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found it!**
I had to go into the SOLUTION FILE and remove the following (by-hand)

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 8
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = https://yournamehere.visualstudio.com/
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = Data\\Data.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName1 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName1 = Data
    SccLocalPath1 = Data
    SccProjectUniqueName2 = Framework\\Framework.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName2 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName2 = Framework
    SccLocalPath2 = Framework
    SccProjectUniqueName3 = Models\\Models.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName3 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName3 = Models
    SccLocalPath3 = Models
    SccProjectUniqueName4 = Dictionary\\Dictionary.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName4 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName4 = Dictionary
    SccLocalPath4 = Dictionary
    SccProjectUniqueName5 = Web\\Web.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName5 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName5 = Web
    SccLocalPath5 = Web
    SccProjectUniqueName6 = Cloud\\Cloud.ccproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName6 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName6 = Cloud
    SccLocalPath6 = Cloud
    SccProjectUniqueName7 = UnitTests\\UnitTests.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName7 = Guardians.sln
    SccProjectName7 = UnitTests
    SccLocalPath7 = UnitTests
EndGlobalSection
```

Answer (score 0):

In the solution's and projects' folders you will find `*.vspscc` files which are responsible of version control, remove them all and your problem should be fixed.

There is also a `.vs` and `$tf` hidden folders, you need to remove those also.

Comment: Sorry, but there are no vspscc files - unbinding removed them.  This is why I am preplexed

Comment: Even inside projects' folders?